# Adding Multiple attachments using yogiben

Tags: meteor, attachment

i am changing the question because i have decided to work with yogiben package..i want to include multiple attachment in my web app..following is my schema for attachment...
`attachments:{
        type: [Object],
        optional: true,
        autoform:{
            afFieldInput: {
                type: 'fileUpload',
                collection: 'Images',
                label: 'Choose file',
            }
        }
    },
    "attachments.$.id":{
        type:String,
        autoform:{
            afFieldInput: {
                type: 'fileUpload',
                collection: 'Images',
                label: 'Choose file',
            }
        }
    },`
and this is the FScollection i used

`var imageStore = new FS.Store.GridFS("images",{});
    Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
        stores: [imageStore],
        filter: {
        maxSize: 10000000, // in bytes
        allow: {
          contentTypes:` ``````````````['image/*','text/plain','application/vnd.openxmlformats-  officedocument.presentationml.presentation','application/pdf','application/msword','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet','application/vnd.ms-excel','application/xls','application/x-xls','application/zip','application/octet-stream','application/x-compressed','application/x-zip','application/x-zip-compressed'],
      extensions: ['png','tif','pptx','jpeg','jpg','doc','docx','pdf','xlsx','xls','txt','gif','zip']
    },
    onInvalid: function (message) {

```
  Materialize.toast(message,4000,'alert-failure');;
}
```

}
});

Answer (score 0):

yogiben:autoform-file is the one I use, but you can find a nice amount of other packages here.

https://atmospherejs.com/packages/File%20Upload

Answer (score 0):

You can also use collection FS.
They also provided a good documentation.
Here is [Link](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS)